# Utilizar font-awesome con Vuejs & Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Vuejs y nuxtjs y no consigo que los iconos de font-awesome se muestren por pantalla.
He buscado en distintas [páginas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome) y ponen que se introduzcan los siguientes comandos para instalar librerias pero no he tenido resultado:

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons

$ npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome

He utilizado el siguiente codigo y no ha funcionado:

```
<i class="fas fa-check" />

<font-awesome-icon icon="check" />
```

Comment: Y estas haciendo los import tambien?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Y estas haciendo los import tambien? – gbianchi♦ el 27 ago. a las 12:31
> Al final parece que añadiendo las siguientes lineas en el archivo nuxt.config.js funciona:

```
css: [
'@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css']

pluggins: [
'~/plugins/fontawesome.js']
```

Answer (score -1):

La primera respuesta es muy buena, pero igual hay un paqeute optimizado con muchas opciones de exportacion espero te sirva, yo lo he usado y te ayuda a optimizar los iconos que realmente necesitas: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/fontawesome

```
buildModules: [   [
  '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
  {
    component: 'fa',
    suffix: true,
    icons: {
      // if you have bought the Pro packages
      // list the icons you want to add, not listed icons will be tree-shaked
      solid: [
        'faChevronDown',
        'faChevronUp',
        'faSignInAlt',
        'faSignOutAlt',
        'faCheck',
        'faSearch',
        'faCloudUploadAlt',
        'faEye',
        'faEdit',
        'faTimes',
        'faCheckCircle',
        'faExchangeAlt',
        'faClock',
        'faSave',
      ],
      // include all icons. But dont do this.
      regular: [
        'faBell',
        'faSnowflake',
        'faCheckSquare',
        'faTimesCircle',
        'faSadCry',
        'faClock',
        'faMoneyBillAlt',
        'faSave',
      ],
      brands: [
        'faGithub',
        'faFontAwesome',
        'faWpforms',
        'faFacebook',
        'faInstagram',
        'faTwitter',
        'faPaypal',
      ],
    },
  },
],]
```

Como ves exportar los iconos es muy sencillo y los tendras disponibles en SVG y ahorraras mucho espacio de compilado